# What is a more efficient and collaborate way of merging branches that has too many commits?

Tags: git, merge, merge-conflict-resolution

We are a medium level organization with around 40 developers. We have multiple branches for different releases for simultaneous development.

The problem that we face when we merge release-branch on master is, there are two many commits involved and overwhelming to understand all the changes that went in and developer who is merging branches is unable to decide which chunks to let in and which to not. Sometimes auto-merged files themselves are catching lots of wrong merges.

How do big companies go about doing these merges in more efficient and collaborative way? Any popular git workflows you are aware of? something like they create a new merged branch and ask all the developers to check/comment if merge properly happened and they actually merge to master?

Please advice

Comment: What did you do in the end? Did you use Pull Requests?

Comment: Using pull requests @JérômeBrunel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you look at pull requests.

They are a good way to look at what has changed from one branch to another and, because you can add as many approvers as you wish, many developers can review it easily and comment wherever they want, creating a discussion about the changes that are about to be merged.

In my experience, we used it on Atlassian Stash and it was a really nice to collaborate over a merge. I suggest you look at [this documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/stash/using-pull-requests-in-stash-299570995.html#UsingpullrequestsinStash-discussDiscussingapullrequest) from Atlassian, especially the part "Discussing a pull request".

Pull requests are also used a lot on Github, to merge a contribution from a fork to the initial repository. More information about Github pull requests can be found [here](https://help.github.com/articles/using-pull-requests/#reviewing-proposed-changes).